# How to check the environment variables of MQ in UNIX

Tags: ibm-mq

Can you please tell how the *environment variable* of **MQ** can be checked in LINUX, AIX or SunOS.
For example how to check MQSNOAUT variable. Thank You.

Comment: Perhaps you want to ask how to _set_ environment variables?

Comment: What are you attempting to do with `MQSNOAUT`?  If this variable is set when the queue manager is created `OAM` is turned off.  If it is set any other time besides queue manager creation it has no impact.  If you want to see if `OAM` is turned off check that the `IPPROCS` are `0` on the `SYSTEM.AUTH.DATA.QUEUE`.  If `IPPROCS` are 1 then OAM is not turned off.  Turning OAM off is not a good solution even in Test/Dev systems and is not something I would recommend you do.

Comment: @JoshMc: Thanks for letting me know that checking ipprocs of the queue 'SYSTEM.AUTH.DATA.QUEUE'  is also the way to know if OAM is enabled/disabled.

Comment: I wrote this up as a answer, if you like it please accept it.  I think you new have enough reputation to upvote answers as well, this is also appreciated .

Comment: @JoshMcThank you, I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `MQSNOAUT` variable is set to **any** value when the queue manager is created, OAM is turned off. If the `MQSNOAUT` variable is set any other time besides queue manager creation it has no effect.  This is documented on the IBM MQ v7.1 Knowledge Center page "[MQSNOAUT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/cs12405_.htm)":

> When you set this variable it disables the object authority manager
>   (OAM) and prevents any security checking.
>
> **The MQSNOAUT variable only takes effect when a queue manager is
>   created.**

---

If you want to check if the `MQSNOAUT` variable is set before you run the `crtmqm` command to create a new queue manager, on Unix you can as provided by @buzyjess just run the following:

```
echo $MQSNOAUT
```

---

If you want to check if OAM is turned off on a running queue manager run the following command:

```
DIS QL(SYSTEM.AUTH.DATA.QUEUE) IPPROCS
```

If the `IPPROCS` has a value of 0 the OAM is turned off on the queue manager.

---

Turning off OAM  is not a good solution even on Test/Dev queue managers and is not something I would recommend you do.  By leaving OAM **turned on** you are able to set things up properly as you would in a production environment, this will leave no surprises when you are ready to move to production.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to know the value of the environment variable ?

```
echo $variable_name
```

Or
Check whether it is set ?

```
set | grep variable_name
```

Comment: I have checked and it does not show any values, which should not be the case. Thank you for your quick response. echo $MQSNOAUT     

$ set | grep MQSNOAUT     
$ echo $MQSNOAUT

Comment: That means, that the environment variable is not set.